# Repair SSD via windows recovery CD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, diskpart

I managed to brick my SSD with windows 10 installed on it. I can't remember exactly what I did to brick it but I've managed to get the BIOS to recognise the SSD again and now I'm using the windows recovery CD to get to a command prompt and diskpart. I can see the SSD in diskpart but it says it has no volumes so I can't use the repair command on it. I've tried automatic repair to no avail. I've struggled to get to this point, any suggestions?

Comment: What did you do to get "BIOS to recognise" it again?

Comment: Under "Hard Drive BBS Priorities" I made the SSD ( the one I couldn't see as a boot option) the highest priority. This is the [link](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3288911/ssd-suddenly-auto-booting-boot-bios.html) the last comment.

Comment: Based on the things you've mentioned I'm not going to assume there is actually anything wrong with the firmware just possible configuration and initialization issues. Could possibly be a buggy BIOS/UEFI as well. Would have to investigate. In general however when you update firmware on an SSD it wipes the partition table and sometimes other metadata specific to the hardware.

Comment: So before your SSD must have just not been bootable? But now your SSD doesn't have any volumes detected anymore. That might be normal considering the firmware update. The question is do you need to recover data off the drive or do you just need a new working drive?

Comment: this is essentially what happened. I was installing Ubuntu on a second SSD.  This caused the first ssd with windows 10 to behave strangely (buggy etc). I then believe I updated the MBR or did something via command prompt to brick the windows 10 ssd. Maybe I modified the drive letter, im not to sure, all I know is that there are currently no recognisable volumes on my windows 10 ssd when I'm using diskpart and I have to boot via recovery mode to my ubuntu SSD. I use terminal in ubuntu to list what disks are on my computer and the SSD with windows does not show up.

Comment: Go into your Ubuntu and add the output of the command `sudo lsblk` to your question.

Comment: Here you go: [link](https://imgur.com/a/o0X0h)
sbd is a separate 2TB SATA drive that's fine. sda is the ssd that linux is installed from and sd0 is my cd-drive.

Comment: So the issue is that it should have a Windows partition thats no longer there?

Comment: yes, it should have a windows partition that is no longer there. I can only see the harddrive with the missing windows partition when I boot the windows recovery CD using command prompt and diskpart. The harddrive with the missing windows partition cannot be seen at all in ubuntu.